# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

Facing issue with connecting to a SQL Server using AD authentication through a spark program.

The JDBC URL being passed is in below format:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>;database=<dbname>;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;port=<port>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=ntlm"
```

Can someone please help with the issue.

Comment: @KenWhite The login to above host is managed through AD authentication. If I remove integratedSecurity=true from the JDBC URL I would essentially be using sql authentication which won't work either. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The error message tells you specifically that you cannot use integrated authentication, because the login is coming from an untrusted domain. You can't use that form of authentication at all.